# From C#, how to set default Crystal Report parameter but still see this parameter in the parameter dialog

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In designed my report to have a parameter called P_FISCAL_YEAR. This is a text only field (No dropdown) that does not allow NULLs. The "Default Value" of this field is "2018-19" as set in the CR parameter editor.

When launching the report, it correctly pops the following Crystal Reports parameter dialog with the proper default fiscal year.
[image: CR Parameter Dialog]

I am launching the report from C# code and I would like to be able to change the P_FISCAL_YEAR *default value* hard coded in the report without changing the .rpt file (Which contains 2018-19).

When I try `myReport.SetParameterValue("P_FISCAL_YEAR", "2019-20");` this does not seems to set the default value but it sets the value itself meaning that the whole P_FISCAL_YEAR parameter field dissapear from the CR parameter dialog:
[image]

In the end, I would like to have the first popup (In the first image) with the P_FISCAL_YEAR parameter but with a different value than "2018-19" (In current case, "2019-20"). This would set something "accurate" in the textbox leaving the user a chance to type something else.

I'm on VS2017 with CR 13.0.24.

Comment: Did you try? uncheck File -> Options -> Reporting -> Save Data With Report.

Comment: @ItiTyagi, I do not have this exact option in VisualStudio but my problem is not in the report editor (Or launcher).  I need to set this default parameter from C# code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588296/crystal-reports-parameters-c-sharp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907506/crystal-report-with-parameters-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp , also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838307/passing-parameter-to-the-crystal-report-through-c-sharp-in-asp-net did not help?

Comment: @ItiTyagi No, setting tht parameter using `SetParameterValue(...)` do its job to set the parameter value but when the Cristal Report dialog to get other parameters (P_PROJECT_NAME and P_REVISION_NUMBER) pops, the P_FISCAL_YEAR is hidden so the user can't change it.  I really want to change the default value of P_FISCAL_YEAR which will be displayed in the CR parameter dialog.

Comment: It is difficult to understand, when Fiscal year is hidden, why it is visible here? Please make a case and problem, and expectation in the question.

Comment: See updated question

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found, after setting the parameters value to the report:

```
.SetParameterValue("ParameterName1", YourParameterValue1);
.SetParameterValue("ParameterName2", YourParameterValue2);
```

is to run the report and then refresh the report.

```
// Run the Report with the parameters set
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
// Show the parameters dialog with the parameters value used to run the report
crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Thank you but I ended up programming a complet UI to launch the report